# How to extract markers from styled Google Maps (www.oilsandsmagazine.com)

Tags: web-scraping, google-maps-markers

I would like to extract the marker locations from [this Canadian oil sands mines](http://www.oilsandsmagazine.com/projects/oilsands-mining) map.

The markers are static PNGs hosted on [Squarespace](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52abb9b9e4b0cb06a591754d/t/576caaf8ff7c50e4acb4bda5/1466739449082/17.png) linked via bit.ly.

[This XHR trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230903/extracting-marker-coordinates-from-embedded-google-map) didn't work in that case.

May you please help me?

Comment: So where are those markers  on that map?

Comment: Just wait until the maps loads: The markers are where the oil sand mine are located.

Comment: Fully downloaded page looks as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJUZ2.png) for me, there are no [such](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52abb9b9e4b0cb06a591754d/t/576caaf8ff7c50e4acb4bda5/1466739449082/17.png) markers.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Should look like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/38455694/41006038-2b63ef9a-6920-11e8-82b0-0edef0869561.png).

Comment: I'm using Chrome 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit), tried IE 11 with the same result. Connecting via UK proxy helped, now I see that markers.

Comment: I would get insight into Google maps API encoding for logged XHRs query string parameters (selected string on screenshots [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQ2P.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnDAJ.png)).